# How to make TCP program binding to any network interfaces?

Tags: linux, networking, router, c++, sockets

I have a client / server network application using Boost ASIO TCP socket. The client is running on an embedded Linux system where multiple network interfaces available (WiFi, cellular, etc), at any time there is only one network interface is up and signed IP address, if the interface is down, another interface is up and signed IP address. The trouble I've got is when the application creates TCP socket in one available interface, it can transfer data to the remote server, but when the interface is down, another interface is up, the client application still transfers the data to the remote server using the same down interface resulting that the server cannot receive the data. I thought that the Linux OS route should be able to handle network interface failover, user TCP application should not need to worry about the network interface change. Appreciate any tips to fix the program.

The same problem I can see in laptop running Ubuntu 18 with both Ethernet and WiFi as well, if I run ssh connected to a remote site when Ethernet is connected, when I pulled off Ethernet cable, the WiFi is still connected but the ssh frozen, it cannot divert the connection by OS route.

Thank you.

Kind regards,

- j

---

> Are you talking about an existing TCP connection switching interfaces when one interface goes down? This won't work, TCP is not multi-homing, so this is a flaw of the protocol, and not Linux. OTOH listening on TCP socket will by default use all interfaces, as will opening a TCP connection.

Yes, an existing TCP connection switching interfaces when one interface goes down.

> If you control both sides in your client-server application, consider using a multi-homing protocol like SCTP or Multipath TCP.

Yes, I control both sides of client server applications. I use Boost ASIO socket, will check if boost support Multipath TCP or not.

> There are other ways to handle failover of physical links like bonding, but they also require you to be able to control both sides.

Yes or no, I control both sides of client server applications, but I only control server platform site not the client platform site I can suggest client site to change network operation, will that work?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Are you talking about an existing TCP connection switching interfaces when one interface goes down? This won't work, TCP is not multi-homing, so this is a flaw of the protocol, and not Linux. OTOH *listening* on TCP socket will by default use all interfaces, as will *opening* a TCP connection.

If you control both sides in your client-server application, consider using a multi-homing protocol like [SCTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_Control_Transmission_Protocol) or [Multipath TCP](https://www.multipath-tcp.org/).

> I thought that the Linux OS route should be able to handle network interface failover

It doesn't and never did, and neither does any other existing implementation of TCP and UDP. In the same way you can't easily use multiple ISPs at the same time, which is a FAQ.

There are other ways to handle failover of physical links like bonding, but they also require you to be able to control both sides.

**Edit**

Depending on what is between your server and your client, this part of the network may or may not let SCTP through (in doubt, test).

For most embedded Linux systems, you should be able to recompile the kernel, which is what you'll need for Multipath TCP.

If you can't do this, you are probably stuck with this problem - then the only workaround is to detect if an interface goes down, and re-open the connection from the client (assuming the server has a known IP).

Comment: I guess what causes OP's misunderstanding is that standard routing indeed handles failover, but **in one direction (outgoing) only** -- it cannot alter the TCP connection's "source" IP address (without MP-TCP), nor does it have any other way to "attract" inbound traffic through the alternate uplink. So the TCP connection can _technically_ still send data through the new uplink just fine, but it will never receive ACKs, and eventually times out.